# During onclick event of radio button, hide the validation and check the another radio value to go to next div class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two radio buttons one is *Enter your own sizes* and another one is  *Choose your standard size*. I have first checked the enter your own sizes. If i click next the jquery  validation is working fine, but I am clicking the enter your standard sizes radio button only. Click the bed type and dimension go to next div it asking the first enter your sizes. If i click the radio only check one function and get in to the next div.

```
 <html>
  <style>
   .dimension 
     {
  display: none;
}

.radio-buttons
{
    display:none;
}
input[type=radio] + label
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    }
input[type=radio]:checked + label
{
    background-image: none;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <body>       <form id="samplecode" name="samplecode" method="POST" action="">                          
        <div id='div1'>
              <div class="col-md-12" >
              <div class='row'>
                  <div class="col-md-7 step-function">
                       <div class="form-group ">
                                          <label class="one-step" >Step Three:Choose Dimension</label>
                       </div>
                                                                                                                         <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="radio-inline btn-radio"><input type="radio" name="size" value="v" >Choose From Standard Size</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline btn-radio"> <input type="radio" name="size" checked="checked" value="s"/>Enter Your Own Size</label>
                            </div>
                                                                                                   <!-- enter your own size --> 
                     <div class='row desc' id="sizes" >
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="own-size">Your Own sizes(in Inches)</label>
                         </div>
                                                                         <form  id="lengthform" name="samplecode" method="POST">
                              <div class="col-md-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3"><input type="text" name="length"  id="length" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Length'></div>
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-lg-3 "> <input type="text"  name="breadth" id="breadth" class="form-control len-class" Placeholder='Breadth'></div>
                             </div>
                          </form>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 ">
   <label class="not-sure-matters" >Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label>
                            </div>

                                 <div class="col-md-12 ">
     <a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <!-- END your own size -->  
                        <!-- enter your Standard  size -->      
                     <div class='row desc' id="sizev" style='Display:none;' >
                         <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label class="own-size">Bed Type</label>
                                <div class='custom-btn-grp'>
                                <div class="bed_type">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li> 
                                            <input type="radio" id="b1"  name="radios"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn" value="Single" checked >
                                            <label for="b1">Single</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="b2" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="Double" >
                                            <label for="b2">Double(Twin)</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="b3" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="Queen" >
                                            <label for="b3">Queen</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="b4" name="radios" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  value="King" >
                                            <label for="b4">King</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                               <label class="own-size">Dimension</label>
                               <div class='custom-btn-grp dimension-group'>
                                <div  class ="dimension" id="d1">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li> 
                                            <input type="radio" id="single1"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  name="single" value="1000s" >
                                            <label for="single1">72x30</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="single2" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"   name="single" checked value="2000s" >
                                            <label for="single2">72x36 </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="single3" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  name="single" value="3000s" >
                                            <label for="single3">75x36</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="single4" class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  name="single" value="4000s" >
                                            <label for="single4">78x36</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="single5"  class="radio-buttons bed-di-btn"  name="single" value="5000s" >
                                            <label for="single5">84x36</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class ="dimension" id="d2">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="doubles1" class="radio-buttons"  name="doubles" checked value="1000d" >
                                            <label for="doubles1">72x48</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="doubles2" class="radio-buttons"  name="doubles" value="2000d" >
                                            <label for="doubles2">75x48</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="doubles3" class="radio-buttons"  name="doubles" value="3000d" >
                                            <label for="doubles3">78x48</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="doubles4" class="radio-buttons"  name="doubles" value="4000d" >
                                            <label for="doubles4">84x48</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div  class ="dimension" id="d3">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="queen1" class="radio-buttons"  name="queen"  checked value="1000q" >
                                            <label for="queen1">72x60</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="queen2" class="radio-buttons"  name="queen" value="2000q" >
                                            <label for="queen2">75x60</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="queen3" class="radio-buttons"  name="queen" value="3000q">
                                            <label for="queen3">78x60</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="queen4"  class="radio-buttons"  name="queen" value="4000q">
                                            <label for="queen4">84x60</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class ="dimension" id="d4">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="king1"  class="radio-buttons"  name="king" checked value="1000k" >
                                            <label for="king1">72x72</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="king2" class="radio-buttons"  name="king" value="2000k" >
                                            <label for="king2">75x72</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="king3" class="radio-buttons"  name="king" value="3000k" >
                                            <label for="king3">78x72</label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <input type="radio" id="king4" class="radio-buttons"  name="king" value="4000k" >
                                            <label for="king4">84x72</label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                 </div>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 "><label class="not-sure-matters" >Not sure how to measure your mattress?</label></div>
                             <div class="col-md-12 "><a href='#' class='link-find-out'>Click here to find out</a></div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- End standard sizes --> 
                    </div>

                         <div class='row'>
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                 <img class="cust-image-size" src='img/cust.jpg'>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                     </div>
                 </div> 
            <div class='col-md-7'>
                 <div class='pull-right'>
                             <a href='#' id='summer5' class='next-color'>Next &#10095&#10095;</a>
                           </div>
                          <div class=' pull-left' >
                              <a href='#Pre' id='summer4' class='next-color'><span>&#10094&#10094;</span>Previous </a>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </form>
       <div id="div2" style="display:none;">HI You successfully reached the solution</div>

     </body>
```

//  Jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>   

<script   src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js"   type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#samplecode').validate({
           rules: {
           length: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            range: [72, 84]
        },
         breadth: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            range: [72, 84]
        }
    },
    messages: {

     length: {
            required: 'Please select a template'
        },
        breadth: {
            required: 'Please select a template'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(){
    $('div[id ^=div]').hide();
    $("#div2").show();
     return false;
    }
    });
     $("#summer5").click(function() {
     $("#samplecode").submit();
     });
        $("#length").change(function(){
         var length =$(this).val();
         $("#breadth").change(function(){
            var breadth =$(this).val();
            var result =length.concat(breadth);
             alert(result);
         });
         });

        $("input[name$='size']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        //alert(test);
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#size" + test).show();
        });
        $(window).load(function()
        {
        $('.dimension').hide();
        $('#d1').show();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ="&#8360;&nbsp;"  +  1000;
        });
        $('.bed_type ul li ').click(function()
        {
        var i = $(this).index();
        $('.dimension').hide();
        $('#d' + (i+1)).show();
        var type  ='b' + (i+1);
        document.getElementById(type).addEventListener("click", bedtype);
        });

        });
     </script>
      </html>
```

Comment: can you make a small demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: probably its not working in js fiddle you combine the code check in w3 schools.com is working fine all script url are in that code dnt worry about that.thanqs for rplying\